# replace a message and not insertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code that shows an html message after the upload, but i want to replace the messages and not accumulate a list of messages like:

valid image
invalid image
invalid format
success upload
....

```
  $('#userfile').change(function() {
                $(this).upload('xxx.php', function(res) {
                    $(res).insertAfter(this);
                }, 'html');
            });
```

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DIV and replace the content every time

```
$('#userfile').change(function() {
            $(this).upload('xxx.php', function(res) {
                $("#someDivID").html(res);
            }, 'html');
        });
```